# Samba users are writing files with the same owner

Tags: ubuntu, samba, chmod

I created a Samba share and 3 users (Marc, Mary and Paul), both in Ubuntu (12.04 LTS) and Samba.
Then I configured 3 Win7 computers to access the share, each with different credentials.

I created 3 folders, one for every user, and chown'd them to the related user, chmod'd them to 0700 and even restarted Samba.

Every time that Mary or Paul create a file or a directory in the share, it ends up to be owned by Marc. They all can access the Marc folder, but none can open Mary's or Paul's.

Can you help me with this problem? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your samba configuration too? Especially the users part.

Comment: I double-checked the smb.conf before posting it, and suddenly I realized that there was a "force user = marc" in the middle of it. I removed it and now everything is working fine.
Thanks for asking, it was helpful! :)

Comment: @Alex Please could you post the above comment as an answer, and accept it, this way, the question isn't left open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I double-checked the smb.conf before posting it, and suddenly I realized that there was a

```
force user = marc
```

in the middle of it. I removed it and now everything is working fine. Thanks for asking, it was helpful! :)